# Auto funded old wallet

Tags: copay

Some time ago I lost my phone with copay installed on it. I also dont know my seed info. Not a big deal I had no funds in the wallet. 
Sadly I forgot I used that address for auto pool payouts. Yesterday that pool payed out, and I can not access the wallet (no seed).
How do i get that btc back?

Answer (score 2):

Like all true Bitcoin wallets, the Copay wallet secures your Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash **only** on your device. To restore your wallet if your device is lost or stolen, you must save the 12-word backup phrase that you receive when you create a wallet. Without this recovery phrase, you will not be able to recover your funds.